# database.yml setup is failing due to an uninitailzed 'tr' method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im attempting to pass ERB to a database.yml very normal action with my other project this one seems to not want to accept the database configs as ERB and only want them as it is

Ive tried to set up dotenv even figaro gems but both yield the same error

ERROR (line 1)

```
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:37:in `initialize': undefined method `tr' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

ERROR(continued)

```
connection_specification.rb:270:in `new'
connection_specification.rb:270:in `resolve_url_connection'
connection_specification.rb:258:in `resolve_hash_connection'
```

database.yml
  `development:
      <<: *default
      database: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
      username: <%= ENV["DATABASE_USER"] %>
      password: <%= ENV["DATABASE_PASS"] %>`

The dotenv file is working for I am not getting a missing development secret key.

Any help is welcomed if i figure it out before then I will post my fix

Comment: What's your database url in env?

Comment: Other information that might be useful: when do you get this error? what does the rest or database.yml look like? Does it work if you put your url, user and pass in database.yml instead of env vars?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like when name spacing was in issue, It did not like that my I had declared 'DATABASE_URL' as a variable instead I had to rename to 'URL_DATABASE'. That was fun, Importance of name spacing is defiantly not to be underestimated.

Answer (score 0):

Amazing, same problem, renamed DATABASE_URL in .rbenv-vars and it worked again...